# Write a function which editUser if the user exist in the users array?

Tags: node.js, arrays, loops, data-structures, javascript-objects

I am using the array.map higher order function with a ternary operator to check the condition. I am not familiar with the method Object.assign

I tried a solution for the question, but it gives no return in the console, please verify and rectify my approach.

```
   const users = [
        {
            name:'Brook', 
            scores:75,
            skills:['HTM', 'CSS', 'JS'],
            age:16
        },
        {
            name:'Alex', 
            scores:80,
            skills:['HTM', 'CSS', 'JS'],
            age:18
        }, 
        {
            name:'David', 
            scores:75,
            skills:['HTM', 'CSS'],
            age:22
        }, 
        {
            name:'John', 
            scores:85,
            skills:['HTM'],
            age:25
        },
        {
            name:'Sara',
            scores:95,
            skills:['HTM', 'CSS', 'JS'],
            age: 26
        },
        {
            name:'Martha', 
            scores:80,
            skills:['HTM', 'CSS', 'JS'],
            age:18
        },
        {
            name:'Thomas',
            scores:90,
            skills:['HTM', 'CSS', 'JS'],
            age:20
        }
        ]
```

My solution: (NodeJS)

```
const editUser = (users, userUpdate) => {
    return users.map((user) => user.name == userUpdate ? Object.assign(user, { scores: userUpdate.scores, skills: userUpdate.skills, age: userUpdate.age }) : user);
}
```

Execution:

```
const userUpdate = {
    name: 'Alex',
    scores: 88,
    skills: ['HTM', 'CSS', 'JS', 'FullStack'],
    age: 20
}
console.log(editUser(users, userUpdate));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

userUpdate is object that contain name property and must be compair user.name with userUpdate.name

in this problem you compair object with name and is not equal.

```
const editUser = (users, userUpdate) => {
    return users.map((user) => user.name == userUpdate.name ? Object.assign(user, { scores: userUpdate.scores, skills: userUpdate.skills, age: userUpdate.age }) : user);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

We sometimes use `object.asign()` for clone an Object in JavaScript (without reference)

```
let user = { name: 'Alex'}
let newUser = user;
newUser.name = 'John';

console.log(newUser); //{ name: 'John' }
console.log(user); // { name: 'John' }
```

If you want to clone an object without reference you can use `Object.assign()` or `three dots (...)` is called `spread operator` in Javascript

I prefer `three dots` because it's a feature of ECS6.

Using of `Object.assign()`:

```
let user = { name: 'Alex'}
let newUser = Object.assign({}, user);
newUser.name = 'John';

console.log(newUser);// { name: 'John' }
console.log(user);//{ name: 'Alex' }
```

Using `three dots (...)` or `spread operator`

```
let user = { name: 'Alex'}
let newUser = {...user};
newUser.name = 'John';

console.log(newUser); // { name: 'John' }
console.log(user); //{ name: 'Alex' }
```

You could visit this [tutorial](https://reactgo.com/javascript-clone-object/) for more examples

For merging objects using `Object.assign()` or 'sperate operator', please check this [tutorial](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/object/javascript-merge-objects/)

**Answer your question is:**

I think you don't need `Object.assign()` because keys of `users` and `userUpdated` is similar so just try like this:

```
const editUser = (users, userUpdate) => {
      return users.map((user) => user.name == userUpdate.name ? userUpdate: user);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the user's `index` within the array with `userUpdate.name`

- The advantage is that in case of many users the search will stop immediately when the user is found

So you can modify that user if `index` is greater than 0

Code:

```js
const users = [{name: 'Brook',scores: 75,skills: ['HTM', 'CSS', 'JS'],age: 16,},{name: 'Alex',scores: 80,skills: ['HTM', 'CSS', 'JS'],age: 18,},{name: 'David',scores: 75,skills: ['HTM', 'CSS'],age: 22,},{name: 'John',scores: 85,skills: ['HTM'],age: 25,},{name: 'Sara',scores: 95,skills: ['HTM', 'CSS', 'JS'],age: 26,},{name: 'Martha',scores: 80,skills: ['HTM', 'CSS', 'JS'],age: 18,},{name: 'Thomas',scores: 90,skills: ['HTM', 'CSS', 'JS'],age: 20,}]

const userUpdate = {
  name: 'Alex',
  scores: 88,
  skills: ['HTM', 'CSS', 'JS', 'FullStack'],
  age: 20,
}

const editUser = (users, userUpdate) => {
  const index = users.findIndex((u) => u.name === userUpdate.name)
  if (index > 0) {
    users[index] = userUpdate
  }
  return users
}
  

const result = editUser(users, userUpdate)

console.log(result)
```